# File Transfer from one system to another in c#

Tags: c#

I Have this c# program which is a client receives the file from the server. Sometimes it works seamlessly. and sometimes it gives an exception in `fileName = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(dataByte, 4, fileNameLen);`.

```
ArgumentOutOfRange Exception
Index and count must refer to a location within the buffer.
Parameter name: bytes
```

If the value of `fileNameLen` is `8` or `12` then it works properly. Otherwise it will be `1330795077`. Why is that? Can anyone explain me why is this? please. Here is my code.

```
        string fileName = string.Empty;
        int thisRead = 0;
        int blockSize = 1024;
        Byte[] dataByte = new Byte[blockSize];
        lock (this)
        {
            string folderPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)+"\\";
            ns.Read(dataByte, thisRead, blockSize);
            int fileNameLen = BitConverter.ToInt32(dataByte, 0);

            fileName = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(dataByte, 4, fileNameLen);
            Stream fileStream = File.OpenWrite(folderPath + fileName);
            fileStream.Write(dataByte, 4 + fileNameLen, (1024 - (4 + fileNameLen)));
            while (true)
            {
                thisRead = ns.Read(dataByte, 0, blockSize);
                fileStream.Write(dataByte, 0, thisRead);
                if (thisRead == 0)
                    break;
            }
            fileStream.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> index and count do not denote a valid range in bytes.

**Encoding.ASCII.GetString()**

ArgumentOutOfRangeException is thrown beacuse of on the following reasons:

- index or count is less than zero.
- index and count do not denote a valid range in bytes.

*Count* is in your case: *fileNameLen*

The Documentation states:

> Data to be converted, such as data read from a stream, can be
>   available only in sequential blocks. In this case, or if the amount of
>   data is so large that it needs to be divided into smaller blocks, the
>   application should use the [Decoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.decoder.aspx) or the Encoder provided by the
>   GetDecoder method or the GetEncoder method, respectively.

See [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/38b953c8.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You would need to check on the contents of `dataByte` when it has been transferred. If you trying to create and integer from `dataByte` and you convert this to Int32 in `fileNameLen` you might receive silly values like `1330795077` and this is no valid index to `Encoding.ASCII.GetString(dataByte, 4, fileNameLen);`

Answer (score 0):

in your code `ns.Read(dataByte, thisRead, blockSize);` should return an int value indicates the actual length read. Use that return value to control how many bytes you want to convert to string to avoid creating silly values.